# Changing jQuery Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, countdown

I have this code and i'm trying to amend it to this.

Ive attached a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaHe/Uq3Eh/)

This is the Code part that I want to change.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#counter').countdown({
        timestamp : (new Date()).getTime() + 51*24*60*60*1000
    });
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#counter').countDown({
        timestamp : (new Date()).getTime() + {
            'day':      1,
            'month':    5,
            'year':     2020,
            'hour':     09,
            'min':      0,
            'sec':      0,
            'utc':    true
        }, omitWeeks: true

    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

I been scratching my head for awhile on how to do it it returns the grey blocks which I want but the jQuery numbers keep flashing and disappear They do not countdown.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A number plus an object make ZERO sense.

Comment: @epascarello sorry i'm really new to jQuery i'm just trying to combine 2 codepens to benefit me.

Answer (score 0):

One immediatelly obvious problem is that this segment

```
(new Date()).getTime() + {
            'day':      1,
            'month':    5,
            'year':     2020,
            'hour':     09,
            'min':      0,
            'sec':      0,
            'utc':    true
        }
```

results in this

```
"1405954137411[object Object]"
```

which is not a number nor a date but a freak of an object.

UPDATE: My guess is that you are trying to set timestamp to 2020

```
new Date(2020,5,1,9,0,0).getTime()
```

if my guess is correct [here's working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq3Eh/1/)

Comment: It is a string...not an object. :)

Comment: Hi LIUFA thanks for the answer but i'm not quite sure what you mean. im trying to replace the first function with the second function. Its basically this [Codepen1](http://codepen.io/Jackreichert/pen/heibs) with this [Codepen2](http://codepen.io/akwright/pen/JxErt).

Comment: @epascarello In a weird word of JavaScript where adding integer and object it indeed ended up being a string, yes :)

Comment: @LIUFA no that isn't correct yet, this is how I would like it [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaHe/Uq3Eh/2/)

Comment: @user3751529 sorry you can't have 'it the way you like it' only the way 'it works' and that way is passing integer and not string.

Comment: @LIUFA No worries LIUFA thanks for the effect I appreciate it, but I will try and figure out away, if I find away I will post it cheers.